# Multilingual website in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, file, visual-studio-2008, globalization, multilingual

This is a part of my multilingual website code . i am getting a runtime error

```
           Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
            rm = new ResourceManager("Resources.Default.apsx", System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("E:\\New folder\\multi_lang\\multi_lang\\App_LocalResources")));
            ci = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
```

Here i am gettingan error in second line saying

1.Make sure you have sufficient privilages to access this resources

1. if you are attempting to access a file, make sure it is not Readonly.

Comment: Can the server access `E:\\New folder\\multi_lang\\multi_lang\\App_LocalResources` ? and does the user that the webserver is running as have permissions to open that file?

Comment: You need to do something like `typeof(MyType).Assembly` where `MyType` is in the same assembly as the resource file you're trying to load.  You aren't going to get an assembly by reading the byte-wise contents of a folder.

Comment: @mellamokb can you please give me the exact code where to write this ?? i really need to completely this project soon

Comment: You might want to be a little less demanding. StackOverflow is not a contractor, and isn't here to do your job.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the person that you're running IIS under has access to:

E:\New folder\multi_lang\multi_lang\App_LocalResources

Under IIS6 it's more than likely IUSR, under IIS7 it needs to be your app pool user: IIS AppPool \ -AppPoolUser-

Comment: Right-click the folder on the machine, and under the security tab grant rights to the appropriate user.